# Can't connect to Windows 2003 Server from WAN via mac RDP client

Tags: windows, mac, networking, remote-desktop

**Question:** How to connect to server from WAN? I have no problems connecting from the LAN, that works fine.

**What I have done:**

- set up port forwarding on router for port 3389, and it points at the Windows server LAN ip, thats all correct.
- nmap scan on the router, can see port 3389 although filtered, but it's open.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I should add when trying to connect from WAN, I'm using a separate ISP.

**EDIT2:** I am using the mac RDP client.

Comment: What is the exact text of the error mstsc gives you when you try to connect. You can hit Ctrl-C while the error dialog box is open and it will copy the text of the dialog window in to your clipboard (A lot of people don't know you can do this, works 90% of the time.)

Comment: Should add I'm connecting from Mac but the error is: "You were disconnected from the windows based computer because of Networking Problems" No error code other than that

The thing is tho, when I set up port forwarding for the screen sharing the macs, they work fine.

Comment: You may want to ask your question on http://apple.stackexchange.com/ instead, or at least update your post to say you are connecting from a mac, most people don't know that RDC is the mac RDP client, that is a pretty important detail that changes a ton of things (a apple tag would be helpful too)